# Can I edit a message sent through a telegram bot within the bot

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to add an emoji prefix to an anonymous messaging bot on Telegram.  Is this possible??  If so how, and where have I gone wrong?

```
def send_msg_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    playerName = update.message.chat.username.lower()
    message = angelOrMortal(playerName, message)
    if players[playerName].chat_id is None or players[playerName].partner.chat_id is None:
        return
    message = angelOrMortal(playerName, update.message)
    if message.text:
        context.bot.send_message(
            text=message.text,
            chat_id=players[playerName].partner.chat_id
        )
    else:
        sendNonTextMessage(message, context.bot, players[playerName].partner.chat_id)


def angelOrMortal(playerName, message):
    if players[playerName].isAngel:
        if message.text:
            message.text = '\U0001F47C' + message.text
        else:
            message.caption = '\U0001F47C' + message.caption
        return message
    else:
        if message.text:
            message.text = '\U0001f476' + message.text
        else:
            message.caption = '\U0001f476' + message.caption
            return message
```

Answer (score 0):

`update.message` represents the incoming message as reported by Telegram. I consider making changes to the objects in `update` bad practice, as these changes are not related to anything that happens on Telegram.

I recommend to change your function `angelOrMortal` such that it just returns a string, which is the text that you want to send.

Note also that you can directly use emoji in python code, e.g. `return '' + message.caption`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.